# Socket connection will disconnect when client close file

Tags: android, sockets, python-3.x

I'm trying to receive img by using socket server in python 3.4, and the client is using android.I have finished write img.But the problem is the client close the img file, then connection will disconnect too.How can I solve this problem?

My server code is as follows:

```
import socket
import struct
import sys
address = ("10.0.0.22", 5000)
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except (socket.error, msg):
    print ('Failed to create socket.Error code:' + str(msg[0]) + ', Error    message: ' + msg[1])
sys.exit()
print ('Socket Created')
s.bind(address)
s.listen(5)

while True:
    (client, addr) = s.accept()
    print ('got connected from', client,addr)
    buf = b''
    while len(buf)<4:
        buf += client.recv(4-len(buf))
    size = struct.unpack('!i', buf)
    print ("receiving %s bytes" % size)

    with open('tst.jpg', 'wb') as img:
        while True:
            data = client.recv(1024)
            print (data)
            if not data:
                break
            img.write(data)
    img.close()
print ('received, yay!')
#write json file
...
with open('a.json','r+') as data_file:
    data = json.dumps(json.load(data_file)).encode('utf-8')
    client.sendall(data)
print('send json, yay!')
client.close()
```

My client code is as follows

```
FileOutputStream fop;
Socket socket;
try {
    fop=new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/dd.jpg");
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fop);
    fop.close();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    InetAddress serverAdd = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.0.22");
    SocketAddress sc_add = new InetSocketAddress(serverAdd,5000);
    socket = new Socket();
    socket.connect(sc_add,2000);

    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    out.write(bytes);
    out.close();
    out.flush();

    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
    byte buffer[] = new byte[1024 * 4];
    int temp = 0;
    while ((temp = inputStream.read(buffer) != -1)){
    System.out.println(new String(buffer,0,temp));
    }
    socket.close();
}
```

Comment: First, in server don't close() the img file again (when you finish the "with" block is closed for you). Second, I see that in the client you close the socket. Keep it open if you want to have it open, you cannot have a connection with only an end, at the server.

Comment: Which line in the client close the socket?The last line?Because last thing client need to do is to get json file.

Comment: Aaah, I think I see your problem now. You look into the input buffer and see nothing so you close the socket. You can check in the while block not only if the buffer is empty but if you received something yet.

Comment: Ok,thank you i will try this.